# How would I change the background colour of my app?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm brand new using Kivy and KivyMD and have looked online but still have no clue how to change the background color according to RGBA in my context. Sorry if it seems like a simple question and answer but I have no clue what to do. My code is below thanks so much for anybody who takes a look at this.

```
KV = '''
<Box@BoxLayout>:

Widget:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 168, 124, 90, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
             

BoxLayout:
        Rectangle:    
        size: self.size
            
'''
            
screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    HomeScreen:
    BreakScreen:
    SettingsScreen
        
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
        
    MDLabel:
        rectangle:
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 168, 124, 90, 1           
        size:500, 500
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.95, 'center_y':0.84}
                
    MDLabel:
        text: "Welcome to"
        font_style: 'H2'
        size:500, 500
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.95,'center_y':0.84}
        
    MDLabel:
        text: "LEAF"
        font_style: 'H3'
        size:500, 500
        pos_hint: {'center_x':1.045,'center_y':0.7}
        
        
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Calendar'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.091,'center_y':0.65}
        on_release:
            app.show_datepicker() 
            
            
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Home'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.076,'center_y':0.57}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'home'
        
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Settings'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.09,'center_y':0.49}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
        
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Continue'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.61,'center_y':0.345}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'home'


    
<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'    
                
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Return to menu'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.61,'center_y':0.345}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    
<BreakScreen>:
    name: 'break'
    
<BreakScreen>:
    name: 'settings'
        
        
"""  

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class BreakScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ScatterTextWidget(BoxLayout):
    text_colour = ObjectProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScatterTextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_label_colour(self, *args):
        colour = [random.random() for i in xrange(3)] + [1]
        self.text_colour = colour

    
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='profile'))
sm.add_widget(BreakScreen(name='upload'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))


class LeafApp(MDApp):
    

    def show_datepicker(self):
        picker = MDDatePicker(callback=self.got_date)
        picker.open()
    
    def got_date(self, the_date):
        print(the_date.year)
        print(the_date.month)
        print(the_date.day)
        
        
        
    data = {
        'mail': 'Gmail', 
        'calendar': 'Calendar', 
        'plus': 'Add Meeting',
    }        


    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen
    
    def set_error_message(self, instance_textfield):
        self.screen.ids.text_field_error.error = True
        
        
        
        
   



LeafApp().run()
```

Comment: What you have in your KV string is a good method: draw a Rectangle with the colour your want. You have one mistake: the rgba values should be floats in the 0-1 range, divide your values by 255 to use this scaling. In this specific case you can also set `Window.clearcolor`, which is the overall app background colour.

Comment: Ok I will try that thanks so much!!